# Error on my windows 10 mobile emulator, Unable to load DLL 'Kernel32.dll'

Tags: visual-studio-2015, emulation, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I am unable to test any app on my emulator today, is anyone having this issue with their window 10 mobile emulator 10.0.10586.0?

I get the following error:
Unable to load DLL 'Kernel32.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Comment: Kernel32 doesn't really exist on mobile. Are you trying to run an app linked against desktop libs?

Comment: Good catch! its a third party lib that works for desktop but not mobile (Appboy I am looking at YOU!)